# Template Alias Difficulty

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, alias, variadic

I have the following:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t End, std::size_t Count, template <typename...> class P,
typename... Accumulated, typename... Added, template <typename, T...> class Z, T... Is, 
std::size_t... Js>
struct Generate<T, End, Count, P<Accumulated...>, P<Added...>, Z<T, Is...>, Js...> :
    Generate<T, End, Count + 1, typename Merge<P, P<Accumulated...>,
        typename AppendEachToPack<T, P, Added, Is...>::type...>::type,
        typename Merge<P, typename AppendEachToPack<T, P, Added, Is...>::type...>::type,
        Z<T, Is...>, Js...> {};
```

and because `typename AppendEachToPack<T, P, Added, Is...>::type...` is being computed twice, I want rewrite the above as

```
template <typename T, std::size_t End, std::size_t Count, template <typename...> class P,
typename... Accumulated, typename... Added, template <typename, T...> class Z, T... Is,
std::size_t... Js>
struct Generate<T, End, Count, P<Accumulated...>, P<Added...>, Z<T, Is...>, Js...> :
    GenerateAlias<T, End, Count + 1, P, P<Accumulated...>, Z<T, Is...>,
    typename AppendEachToPack<T, P, Added, Is...>::type..., Js...> {};
```

where

```
template <typename T, std::size_t End, std::size_t Count, template <typename...> class P,
typename Output, typename Sequence, typename... Expanded, std::size_t... Js>
using GenerateAlias = Generate<T, End, Count, typename Merge<P, Output, Expanded...>::type,
typename Merge<P, Expanded...>::type, Sequence, Js...>;
```

But the two packs declaration `typename... Expanded, std::size_t... Js` is not accepted.  So how do I achieve what I want to achieve?

In case you need it, here are the definitions of `AppendToEachPack` and `Merge`:

```
// Appending an element to a pack.
template <typename T, T t, typename> struct Append;

template <typename T, T t, template <T...> class Z, T... Is>  
struct Append<T, t, Z<Is...>> {  
    using type = Z<Is..., t>;
};

// Appending many elements to a pack one at a time.
template <typename T, template <typename...> class P, typename Pack, T... Is>
struct AppendEachToPack {
    using type = P<typename Append<T, Is, Pack>::type...>;
};

// Merging multiple packs of types into a single pack of types.
template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Packs> struct Merge;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename Pack>
struct Merge<P, Pack> {
    using type = Pack;
};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct Merge<P, P<Ts...>, P<Us...>> {
    using type = P<Ts..., Us...>;
};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename Pack1, typename Pack2, typename... Packs>
struct Merge<P, Pack1, Pack2, Packs...> {
    using type = typename Merge<P, Pack1, typename Merge<P, Pack2, Packs...>::type>::type;
};
```

Comment: Not really possible with alias templates alone. If you need to pass more than one pack, you need a holder and then extract using either partial specialization or function template + `decltype`. And I think this concern about "`typename AppendEachToPack<T, P, Added, Is...>::type...` being computed twice"  is rather misguided in any event due to memoization. What exactly is `Generate` supposed to do?

Comment: As an example, `Create<int, A, Pack, 3,2, 2,3>` will generate a `Pack` of `A<Is...>`'s where the first 2 components will be 0,1,or 2, and the next 3 components will be 0 or 1.  I've already solved it fully, but I just want to finish some optimization.  Perhaps `Expanded...` and `Js...` can be wrapped by two packs, so then the compiler will accept the syntax?

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly: the resulting pack from your example has 3*3*2*2*2 = 72 members, each of which is of the form `A<x,y,z,w,u>`, where `x` and `y` are from {0, 1, 2} and `z`, `w`, and `u` are from {0, 1}?

Comment: Almost.  But that's not the problem. I've already solved it. I just want to learn how to avoid the duplicate computations. If you want I can post my full solution in a link, so you can see what the original goal was.  Here is the link, so you can run it and see the output:  http://ideone.com/EK7H5y

Comment: Hmm, why do you have stuff like `0 0` in your output? As to "duplicate computation", the compiler memoizes the template specializations it already instantiated, so that's generally a non-issue.

Comment: That is part of the spec.  `A<Is...>` can have any number of template arguments, so `A<0>`, `A<0,0>`, `A<0,0,0>` are part of the generation too.  It's not supposed to generate same-sized A's.  So you are saying don't bother with the issue?  Isn't computing it once always better than computing it twice?  What if `AppendEachToPack<T, P, NewlyAdded, Is...>::type...` takes 30 seconds to compute once?

Comment: Then it takes, say, 30.5 seconds to compute "twice".

Comment: I see.  But I still want to try the optimization anyway.  I think I understand your original hint on how to do it and will post my solution if I succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to T.C.'s hint, here is one solution (tested to work correctly):

```
// Helper struct to forward the pack wrapping the problem pack.
template <template <typename...> class P, typename PackOfPacks, typename... OtherPacks>
struct MergeMany;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Packs, typename... OtherPacks>
struct MergeMany<P, P<Packs...>, OtherPacks...> : Merge<P, Packs..., OtherPacks...> {};

// Now the desired GenerateAlias.
template <typename T, std::size_t End, std::size_t Count, template <typename...> class P,
    typename Output, typename Sequence, typename Expanded, std::size_t... Js>
using GenerateAlias = Generate<T, End, Count, typename MergeMany<P, Expanded, Output>::type,
    typename MergeMany<P, Expanded>::type, Sequence, Js...>;

// And now using GenerateAlias, so typename AppendEachToPack<T, P, Added, Is...>::type... is computed only once.
template <typename T, std::size_t End, std::size_t Count, template <typename...> class P, typename... Accumulated,
typename... Added, template <typename, T...> class Z, T... Is, std::size_t... Js>
struct Generate<T, End, Count, P<Accumulated...>, P<Added...>, Z<T, Is...>, Js...> :
    GenerateAlias<T, End, Count + 1, P, P<Accumulated...>, Z<T, Is...>,
    P<typename AppendEachToPack<T, P, Added, Is...>::type...>, Js...> {};
```